# Bluebird promises on Node.js: error and exception handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I use bluebird promises for a node.js application (MEAN environment). I am having trouble understanding exception/error handling though. Consider the following code:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird'),
    library1 = Promise.promisifyAll(require('firstlibrary')),
    library2 = Promise.promisifyAll(require('secondlibrary'));

//main
exports.urlchecker = function(req, res) {
    library1.doSomething(req.body.url) //--> how to reject this promise?
        .then(function(response) {
            if (response == false) {
                throw new LinkError("URL invalid!");
            }

            library2.Foo(req.body.url)
                .then(function(response2) {
                    if (response2 == false) {
                        throw new SizeError("URL too long!");
                    }
                    res.json({
                        status: true
                    });
                }).catch(LinkError, function(e) { //--> causes error!
                    res.json({
                        status: false
                    });
                }).catch(SizeError, function(e) { //--> causes error!
                    res.json({
                        status: false
                    });
                }).catch(function(e) { //--> catch all other exceptions!
                    res.json({
                        status: false
                    });
                });
        });
};
```

`library1` - promisified:

```
exports.doSomething = function(url, cb) {
    if (whatever == 0) {
        cb(null, false); //--> what to return to reject promise?
    } else {
        cb(null, true);
    }
};
```

I got two questions now.

1. What do I have to return from `library1` to get its promise rejected? If not by returning a value, how can I do that?
2. How do I define and catch my own exceptions? The code above results in this error:

   ```
   Unhandled rejection ReferenceError: LinkError/SizeError is not defined
   ```

Comment: Depending on the response by library1 I'd like to immediately cut the promise chain (-> library2 will not be called then) and respond an error to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.promisify*()` turns the regular Node.js callback convention into promises. Part of that convention is that errors are passed as first argument to a callback function.

In other words, to reject the promise, use `cb(new Error(...))`.

Example:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var library1 = {
  // If `doFail` is true, "return" an error.
  doSomething : function(doFail, cb) {
    if (doFail) {
      return cb(new Error('I failed'));
    } else {
      return cb(null, 'hello world');
    }
  }
};

var doSomething = Promise.promisify(library1.doSomething);

// Call that resolves.
doSomething(false).then(function(result) {
  console.log('result:', result);
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log('error:', err);
});

// Call that rejects.
doSomething(true).then(function(result) {
  console.log('result:', result);
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log('error:', err);
});
```

As for the missing error types: I assume that they are exported by `secondlibrary` so use `library2.LinkError` instead of just `LinkError`. If they aren't exported you cannot catch them explicitly.

Comment: This is the correct way to do this - it actually doesn't have anything to do with promises it's just how you work with node errbacks. You might want to address the second question too (subclassing error).